# Magento - Getting Quote Object Data of Bundle Product based on user selection

Tags: magento, bundle, product, quote

Is there a valuable way of getting the data of an configured Bundle product before adding it to the quote. Here the scenario:

- User configured the bundle product in the product view
- Add to cart
- I catch the process of adding the product to cart with an event (sales_quote_add_item or sales_quote_product_add_after)
- get the data of the configured bundle product

What data is in the $item. Is this the hole user based and configured Product data

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
```

Is this the associated Product with the item, and if yes what is the difference

```
$product = $item->getProduct();
```

So far I understand is this the user selection

```
    $infoBuyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest()->toArray();
    $bundleOption = $infoBuyRequest['bundle_option'];
```

Here are a few things I don't understand:

How can i get the Options and Selections of the configured Bundle? If I var_dumb the item or product variables I get a lot of data. Not the total Options&Colections, just the ones the user has chosen.

The next question is: is the **$item** the actual object which will be stored in the database (sales_flat_quote_item), so the configured one?

What do I get through **$item->getProduct()**. Is this the associated product data?

How can I get the custom options (stored in different arrays:bundle_selection_attributes, bundle_option_ids, etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bundleproduct is added to the card, following is passed through the observer of the `sales_quote_add_item` event:

1. The bundleproduct.
2. All the underlying simple product one after another.

So if you e.g. have a bundle product, with 4 options to choose a product and quantity, the observer is called 5 times.

In the database, a quote item is stored with the added bundle product and its selected underlying products.

`$item->getProduct()` does return the object of the current quote item.

You can use functions like `$product->getName()` and `$product->getId()`, `$product->getAttributeText('attribute_code')`, etc and all the logical stuff on it in the observer.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is getProduct() and getQuoteItem() returning the same object of the current quote item? What if i want to analyse the bundle quote item structure and e.g. insert new simple product to the bundle object.

Comment: No, it's not the same. You should use getProduct(). Adding a simple product to a bundle object is another (hard) question. Maybe you should make that a whole new question.

Comment: That is Part of the question. Well maybe there will ne more Feedback in the question :) thaks

Comment: Ok, but you didn't mention this in your question. Is my answer useful for the questions you mentioned above?

Comment: sure is usefull. The more important part for me to know how to fetch the options and selections & be able to insert an item through the observer